# Is there a reason to differentiate between static and non-static data members in terms of prohibition of the usage of abstract types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, abstract-data-type

In [`class.abstract`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.abstract#note-3) we can see in the *Note 3* that:

> An abstract class can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it ([basic.def], [class.mem]).

This rules out the usage of abstract classes as subobjects and it makes sense to me (though this is just a note, which is non-normative, IIRC).

However, in [`class.mem`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-16) we can read that:

> The type of a **non-static** data member shall not be an incomplete type ([basic.types]), an abstract class type ([class.abstract]), or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.
> [*Note 5: In particular, a class C cannot contain a **non-static** member of class C, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class C. — end note*]

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

What seems strange to me is the specific wording: "**non-static**". Why is it explicitly stated that this refers to non-static members? I don't believe we're allowed to have `static` declarations or definitions of objects of abstract types. Does the standard actually allow `static` data members to be abstract and no sane compiler implements that? Or it does prohibit such uses (in that case why the distinction in static vs non-static data in the aforementioned paragraph)?

Comment: @AdrianMole I fail to see where you're going with this and how would that matter

Comment: The fact that the rule doesn't cover `static` data members doesn't imply that it allows it. There is going to be some other rule elsewhere that covers that. The standard is hard to read, you usually can't rely on a single passage to get the full picture. This is why sites like cppreference are maintained. The standard often uses "non-static data member" as a single term used to cover "normal class data members". Additionally, if we took out the "non-static" part, the rule would be equally incomplete as it wouldn't cover the exclusion of incomplete types. Somehow it has to be split in two.

Comment: It's not a note. Please check: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.abstract#2

Comment: @rustyx, hm, when you delete that `/n4659` part from the URL, it suddently becomes a note. Additionaly, when I googled the details, it seems that n4659 is 4 years old, which does seem out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not a class is abstract is not known until the class is defined.

It has always been allowed to *declare* a static data member with an incomplete class type, as long as the type is complete by the time the static data member is *defined*. Since the type of a static data member may be incomplete on its *declaration*, it also follows that it might be an abstract class that the compiler doesn't yet know is abstract. For this reason, it is appropriate to defer checking of the abstractness until the static data member's definition. At the time of definition, if the type of the static data member is found to be an abstract class, *then* the compiler should issue a diagnostic. This was the reasoning in [P0929](https://wg21.link/P0929), which added the current wording in C++20.

With non-static data members, their types are required to be complete at the time of declaration, and the declaration of the non-static data member serves as a definition. So the abstractness must be checked at that point.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it explicitly stated that this refers to non-static members?

Because that allows declaration of static members with incomplete type. Here is a minimal example that is allowed, but wouldn't be allowed if "non-static" wasn't explicitly stated in that rule:

```
struct S {
    // array of unknown bound is an incomplete type
    static int arr[];
    //int arr2[]; // is not allowed because of the rule
};

int S::arr[3]; // definition of the static member
```

> Does the standard actually allow static data members to be abstract

No, that would contradict the rule quoted by [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68462217/2079303) unless there was a more specific rule overriding it (and there isn't to my knowledge). <strike>Specifying the rule to non-static seems to be relevant to incomplete types only; and not to abstract types. As such, listing "abstract type" in the rule explicitly seems redundant and thus confusing (but not contradictory) to me</strike> Edit: Brian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68462452/2079303) clarifies why it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In the first quote there is an answer to your question

> An abstract class can be used only as a base class of some other
> class; **no objects of an abstract class can be created** except as
> subobjects of a class derived from it ([basic.def], [class.mem]).

So as a static data member is a separate object relative to object of the class type where it is declared it can not be created as an object of an abstract class. On the other hand, when we are speaking about creating an object of a class type we mean its non-static data members that are sub-objects of the object of the class type. Static data members are instantiated independently of the instantiation of objects of the class where they are declared.

Comment: But it's a note and from what I can recall notes are non-normative - they are not to be treated as rules. In addition I fail to see how the introduction of the "**non-static**" part helps in the second quote at all.

Comment: @Fureeish The C++ 14 Standard (10.4 Abstract classes) "2 An abstract class is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract
class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it"

Comment: @Fureeish Any object of a class type consists from its base class sub-objects and non-static data members when it is instantiated.. Static data members are instantiated separately independently of objects of the class where they were declared.